# Insert into linked list and got TypeError: Cannot set property 'next' of undefined

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I was building a linkedList by using javascript

but i got an error in insert function.

Could someone help me to figure out what should i do?

The output should be [1,10,6,5,16]

The way i insert to linkedList,i referred to this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-linkedlist-javascript/)

i changed

> var node = new Node(element);

to

> const newNode ={
>          value:value,
>          next:null
>         };

Here is my JS:

```js
   

class LinkedList {
  constructor(value) {
    this.head = {
      value: value,
      next: null
    };
    this.tail = this.head;
    this.length = 1;
  }
  append(value) {
    const newNode = { 
      value:value,
      next:null 
    }; // 1
    this.tail.next= newNode;
    this.tail = newNode  // 2
    this.length++;
    return this;
   }
  prehend(value){
    const newNode ={
    value:value,
    next:null
      };
    newNode.next = this.head;
    this.head = newNode;
    this.length++;
    return this;
     }
   printList() {
    const array = [];
    let currentNode = this.head;
    while(currentNode !== null){
         array.push(currentNode.value)
        currentNode = currentNode.next
    }
    return array;
    }
    insert(index, value){
    if(index>0&&index>this.length){
         return false
    }
    else{
      const newNode ={
       value:value,
       next:null
      };
     var curr,prev;
     curr=this.head;
     if(index=0){
        newNode.next=head;
        this.head=newNode;
     }else{
        curr=this.head;
        var it=0;
        while(it<index){
          it++;
         prev=curr;
         curr=curr.next;
         }
         newNode.next=curr;
         prev.next=newNode;
         }
         this.length++
         }
         return this.printList();
         }
 }
let myLinkedList = new LinkedList(10);
myLinkedList.append(5);
myLinkedList.append(16);
myLinkedList.prehend(1);
myLinkedList.insert(2, 6);
myLinkedList.printList();//should return [1,10,6,5,16]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a condition `if(index=0)` which sets `index` to 0, which breaks your code. It should have been `if(index == 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I fix if(index=0) to if(index===0).And It works